# QFileDialog opens twice when checking for improper closing

Tags: pyqt5, qdialog, qfiledialog

I am trying to make a PyQt5 application, I am trying to get that filename out of a `QFileDialog`. However, when trying to actually get the filename after the dialog was accepted, another `QFileDialog` pops out. I do not know how to solve this, here is the code snippet that is blocking me.

```
 from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw

 loadfile = qtw.QFileDialog()

 if loadfile.exec_() != 1:
    pass
 else:
    path = loadfile.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open a file', '', 'All Files (*.*)')
```

As far as I am aware, I am just checking if the user pressed the cancel or the close button here. If not, I call the `getOpenFileName` in the `loadfile` object. But this opens the `QFileDialog` again.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing the `exec` of the dialog and the static functions. Just use the `getOpenFileName` to get the path and selected filter, you don't need to create a QFileDialog instance for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I do not totally understand it. `getOpenFileName` just returns a tuple without any `exec` method. Then I do not know how to check for cancels.

Comment: The tuple is composed by the file path string and the selected filter. If the string is empty, the dialog has been cancelled, as you obviously cannot have selected a file that has no name.

Comment: Damn... this is such a simple solution. I did not even though about that.